# how to search document from sharepoint 2013 document library using c#

Tags: client-object-model

i need C# code for to search documents from SharePoint 2013 document library. i was uploaded documents in SharePoint document library now i want to search all uploaded documents by using c# coding . it will be search also inside the documents.

Answer (score 4):

You can use SharePoint 2013 Search APIs for this. The pre requisites for using this approach is:

1. Search service application created and running with good crawl
   system scheduled.
2. Enable continuous crawl, so that new results will appear.
3. Make sure your document library is set to **YES** to **Allow items to appear in search results** in the Advanced Settings of the doc
   library
4. Also additionally you can set up a search scope for  the document library and use KeywordQuery to search in that scope(You can set the scope at site collection).This step is not a required step since you can put the URL of the document library inside the Query to get only docs from that library.

Below code snippet can be used as a starting point:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://<serverName>/sites/<siteCollectionPath>"))
{
    KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
    keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";//change this to suit your need
    SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
    ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

See this [article](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/01/03/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-2013-search-keywordquery-class.aspx) about KeyWordQuery Class.

See this [article](http://techmikael.blogspot.co.at/2013/04/limiting-search-results-in-sharepoint.html) to know about the Result Sources(Search scope) in 2013.